# Trying to loop through different working Directories

Tags: r

I want to set `Dir` equal to `"//RATES/@Original_Rates/GR-N240"` for the first pass through the for loop.

```
forms <- c("GR-N240", "GR-N250", "GR-N270", "GR-N280")

for(i in forms) {
  Dir <- "//RATES/@Original_Rates/i"
  setwd(DIR)
}
```

Comment: `Dir <- file.path("//RATES/@Original_Rates", i)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function to concatenate paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13110076/function-to-concatenate-paths)

Comment: If you want to use this logic, you will need to use `sprintf("//RATES/@Original_Rates/%s", i)`.