# UNC Path Concatenation in R

Tags: r, path, concatenation, unc

How can I join / concatenate UNC path components in R in a OS agnostic way?

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13110097/3104974) on joining local paths using `file.path()`, but it seemingly doesn't work on UNC paths.

Answer (score 0):

Your UNC Adress might contain `\`. R really hates those. If your UNC paths are shown to you as network drive use `net use` in the commandline (on Windows type cmd in start). There you'll find the remote adress. Then add one `\` in front of every `\`:

like this:
`\\mydomain.adress.drive\projects` to
`\\\\mydomain.adress.drive\\projects`

This happens because R handles `\` as marker for escape characters. like `\n` for new line.

Comment: I can't make the script rely on a network drive since the script may be accessed by other people on their system who don't have this drive-alias then.

Comment: If your script handles data on a network drive, the unc-adress (e.g.`\\mydomain.adress.drive\projects`) always refers to the same folder. If you got a a personal folder for each user (often users got a personal network drive for their stuff mapping to a folder), you can use the normal alias (e.g`H:`). In my experience this usually works but breaks down if you want to build a package or do other stuff where `R CMD` is called. As the commandline for some reason does not use the alias, but the true unc adress and therefore throws an error.